# Defining a function in haskell

Tags: haskell

Why does my function give me an out of scope error?

```
tarefa1 :: [String] -> [String]
tarefa1 linhas = if res == ok then ["OK"] else [show res]
  where
    (tab,coords) = parteMapa conteudo
    erro1 = validaTabuleiro 1 tab
    erro2 = validaCoords (length tab + 1) tab coords
    res = juntaErro erro1 erro2
```

The error:

```
Not in scope: `conteudo'.
```

`conteudo` is supposed to be a .txt document that I have in a different file, but I don't know how to make it to load it in this function.

Comment: The result of a function, in pure functional programming, can only depend on the function arguments. You need to either take `conteudo` as an additional parameter (and access the file elsewhere) or return `IO [String]` and actually access the file in this function.

Comment: By the way, the question is poorly written: you seem to perfectly _know_ why using `conteudo` triggers the not in scope error. Namely, you did not define it as the result of reading your file.

Comment: i cant do the IO String. and when i take conteudo as an additional paramater it gives me an error like '=' or '<-' not in scope.

Comment: maybe we should close this here? Seems @André lost interest and Yuris answer seems good enough IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a good question, since this should be covered by basic Haskell knowledge, and it's clearly homework for those of us who can speak Portuguese. You shouldn't be afraid to ask your teacher for some help, and I'm sure he would be glad to give you that.

Nevertheless, since it is *possible* to answer the question, I will:

Input and Output in Haskell is only possible inside functions that evaluate an IO action (that is, a value of the `IO` type).

Of course, since `main` has type `IO ()`, you can execute IO actions inside of it.

The simplest way to read a file is with the `readFile` function. It accepts a `FilePath` and evaluates to a `IO String` (which has the full contents of the file). I'll give you an example and I hope you can follow from it.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  contents <- readFile "yourfilename.txt" -- because I used "<-", contents has type String
  let fileLines = lines contents -- here I have a [String] with each line of the file
  someFunction fileLines
  return ()
```

`someFunction` should also evaluate an IO action, in this example. You can "put things inside" `IO` using `return`, in case you don't know.